# clicklistener to each android-listview item

Tags: android-listview

Can you please tell me how to set clicklistener to each android listview item? I want mij each item to navigate to different pages.

Right now I wrote the following code that all items go to the same page:

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
startActivity(new Intent(Participant.this,Contact.class)); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course all items navigate to same page...the code is the same for each item!
You have to call a different Intent() for every item, depends on its position or item's view type or every other kind of information.
Check [Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and look its constructor.
Also get a good tutorial (web is full) can help you.
Enjoy.